# What mobi readers for PC are there?

Tags: mobi

Until yesterday I used MobiPocket 6.2 to check my mobi files on my Windows PC before uploading them to my Kindle. Today however MobiPocket keeps crashing when starting the app. I already re-installed it and rebooted my XP PC, but no avail. Are there other mobi readers for PC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Free eBook Reader: http://www.fbreader.org/

Calibre: http://calibre-ebook.com/

And then, of course, you could just use the Kindle software: http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_pc_mkt_lnd?docId=1000426311

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the Amazon reader, guess I should have been. I'll try that one.

Comment: I really like calibre for this, since it runs on most OSes, and does conversions between formats - useful when you have some old palm formatted book ;p

Comment: I downloaded the Kindle reader for PC and don't see any way to import and read a .mobi file.

Comment: No need to "import" or open it... double clicking works fine with the kindle reader:)

Answer (score 3):

I have tried PDB, Mobi, EPUB, Djvu with [Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html). Its simple, starts fast.

Official description:

> Sumatra PDF is a free PDF, eBook (ePub, Mobi), XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic
>   Book (CBZ and CBR) reader for Windows. Sumatra PDF is powerful, small,
>   portable and starts up very fast. Simplicity of the user interface has
>   a high priority.